# $(1)\left | \sqrt[]{x} -\sqrt[]{x+\varepsilon} \right | < \frac{1}{200}, \space \space (2)\left | \sqrt[]{x} -P(x) \right | < \frac{1}{100} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, epsilon-delta

> (1)Find an explicit value of $\varepsilon >0$ such that for every $x\in \left [ 0,1 \right ] $, there always is
> $$\left | \sqrt[]{x} -\sqrt[]{x+\varepsilon}  \right | < \frac{1}{200}$$
>
> (2)Find an explicit integer $N$ such that there exists a polynomial $P$ of degree at most $N$ such that for every $x\in \left [ 0,1 \right ] $, there always is $$\left | \sqrt[]{x} -P\left ( x \right )  \right | < \frac{1}{100}$$

First part of the question, can I do it this way?$$\left | \sqrt[]{x}-\sqrt[]{x+\varepsilon }   \right | =\left | \frac{x-\left ( x+\varepsilon  \right )}{ \sqrt[]{x}+\sqrt[]{x+\varepsilon }  }  \right |\le \left |\frac{x-\left ( x+\varepsilon  \right )}{2\sqrt[]{x} }    \right |=\frac{\varepsilon }{2\sqrt[]{x} }  $$
next, take$$ \frac{\varepsilon }{2\sqrt[]{x} }=\frac{1}{200} $$
therefore, as long as $\varepsilon=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{100}$, the inequality of (1) hold?(honestly, I feel weird.)

And about second part of the question, the only thing I know is that I should use the expansion of $\sqrt{x+\varepsilon}\space$ in power series of $(x-1)$. Could someone give me some example how I do it?

Comment: For the first part: $$\left | \sqrt x-\sqrt{x+\varepsilon}  \right | < \frac1{200}\iff\sqrt{x+\varepsilon}<\frac1{200}+\sqrt x$$
$$\iff x+\varepsilon<\left(\frac1{200}\right)^2+\frac{\sqrt x}{100}+x.$$
This inequality holds for all $x\in[0,1]$ iff $$\varepsilon<\left(\frac1{200}\right)^2.$$ I do not edit this as an answer because I have no idea for the second part.

Comment: For the first part, your upper bound was too big as $x$ tends to $0.$ That makes your solution $\varepsilon$ depend on $x,$ which is forbidden. For the second part, how do you "know" that you "should" do that? Shouldn't you rather use the first part somehow?

Comment: thank you madam,  I know I should use the expansion of  $\sqrt{x+\varepsilon}\space$in power series of $(x-1)$ because the hint of the problem tell me so.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part we have: $\left|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x+\epsilon}\right|= \dfrac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+\epsilon}}\le \dfrac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}=\sqrt{\epsilon} < \dfrac{1}{200}\implies \epsilon < \dfrac{1}{40,000}$. Thus you can take for example $\epsilon = \dfrac{1}{50,000}$ and this epsilon does it for you.

Comment: thank you sir, this helps a lot!